# Getting error in Matlab while try to plot the values from a row of the image

Tags: image, matlab, plot, computer-vision

I want to write a code in Matlab. There is a picture of size (258, 320). It is a color picture. I want to show the image using one color channel. Try to plotting the values from a row of the image.

```
% Color planes
img = imread('fruit.png');
imshow(img);

disp(size(img));

% TODO: Select a color plane, display it, inspect values from a row
img_blue = img(:,:,2);
imshow(img_blue);
plot(img_blue(150,0));
```

I got this error `error: img_blue(_,0): subscripts must be either integers 1 to (2^31)-1 or logicals error: execution exception in main.m`

Can anyone please help m to overcome the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the fact that you're using the indexing from, I guess, Python (as in between 0 and N-1) while Matlab uses indexes starting from 1.

So if you want to plot the first plane, it will be `plot(img_blue(150, 1));` instead of `plot(img_blue(150, 0));`. Similarly, blue is the third main color, so it will actually be `img_blue = img(:, :, 3);` instead of `img_blue = img(:, :, 2);`.

Answer (score 1):

Typically I would display the image of a blue channel by filling in the other channels/layers of the array with 0 before calling `imshow()`, but that's just personal preference. To plot the first row of an image you can index the image  `(1,:)`. Keep in mind MATLAB’s start index for arrays starts at 1 unlike many languages that are base 0 index. Typically the third channel is the blue channel especially in RGB format. At times in libraries such as OpenCV the BGR convention is alternatively used.

### RGB Channel Conventions

[image: RGB Channel Conventions]

---

### Plotting the Blue Channel

[image: Plotting Blue Channel of Image]

```
Image = imread('peppers.png');
[Image_Height,Image_Width,Number_Of_Channels] = size(Image);

Blue_Channel = Image(:,:,3);

Blue_Image(:,:,1) = 0;
Blue_Image(:,:,2) = 0;
Blue_Image(:,:,3) = Blue_Channel;

subplot(1,2,1); imshow(Blue_Image);
title("Blue Channel");
xlabel(num2str(Image_Width) + " Columns"); ylabel(num2str(Image_Height) + " Rows");

Row_Number = 1;
subplot(1,2,2); plot(Blue_Channel(Row_Number,:));
title("Blue Channel Intensities (Row " + num2str(Row_Number) + ")");
xlabel("Column Index"); ylabel("Intensity Value");
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**